# What's a better way to handle input changes in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Everytime i want to update some value in my state via a text input i just simply create an onChange function that accepts a `event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HtmlTextAreaElement>` as an argument. Something like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<IState>({ email: "", password: "" });

const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HtmlTextAreaElement>): void => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  
  setState({
    ...state,
    [name]: string
  });
}
```

And well it perfectly works but... i have to create this function every single time that i want to change my state via an input in other page (an onChange function in the login page, an `onChange` function in sign up page, forgotpassword page... etc). My question is: Is there a way to create a generic `onChange` that accepts any state and update it?

this is my first post on stack overflow, sorry if i dont follow the guidelines at all.

Comment: Generally if it's a form I will just go with the Formik library. Makes life a lot easier dealing with validation, changing values,  disabling buttons based on the state of the form etc. : https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik

Answer (score 1):

If the function is *short* and only used once, then one option you could consider would be to define it inline.

```
<input
  name="name"
  value={state.name}
  onChange={e => { setState({ ...state, name: e.target.value }); }}
/>
```

You can also consider separating out states, as React recommends - there's no need to put everything into a single state variable (unless there are a *lot* of inputs in a form, in which case a single state object with a generic updater can make things more DRY).

```
const [name, setName] = useState(''); // No need for type annotations anymore
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

// ...

<input
  name="name"
  value={name}
  onChange={e => { setName(e.target.value); }}
/>
```

If you want a generic state updater that you don't have to redefine every time to have another state variable, you can create a higher order function that you pass in a state setter, that returns the change handler - then import this function wherever it's needed.

```
const makeChangeHandler = (stateSetter: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>) => {
  return (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HtmlTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    stateSetter({
      ...state,
      [name]: value
    });
  };
};
```

```
<input
  name="name"
  value={name}
  onChange={makeChangeHandler(setState)}
/>
```

Refactoring that function to deal with separate states instead of having a single state object is trivial, if desired, just do

```
stateSetter(value);
```